# Skipping certain numbers in a list

Tags: lists

My organization has developed a template for formal correspondence. The rules states that each line / paragraph has to be numbered. Some of the rules are given below:

1. **Paragraphs.** Arabic numerals are used for paragraphs. The numerals are followed by a full stop.
2. **Sub-paragraphs.** Small alphabets in brackets the alphabets (i) and (o) are used for numbering sub-paragraphs.

I have created a new environment **mylist** for numbering paragraphs and sub-paragraphs. But I do not know how to skip (i) and (o) in the nested lists. I have basic idea of how to achieve it but can not implement it in LaTeX.

For each list, LaTeX creates a counter. For example, for first sub-paragraph, the counter's value is 1, for second sub-paragraph it is 2. Similarly, when counter's value is 9, (i) will be printed. If else conditional statement can be used to skip counter value of 9 and directly jump from 8 (h) to 10 (j). I need help in implementing this in LaTex.

A minimal working example is given below:-

```
\documentclass[oneside, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[mylist]{wide, align = left}

\setlist[mylist, 1]{leftmargin = 0in, label = \arabic*.}
\setlist[mylist, 2]{leftmargin = 0.5in, label = (\alph*)}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}
    
    \item Foo
    
    \begin{mylist}
        
        \item bar
        
        \item bar
        
        \item bar
        
        \item bar
        
        \item bar
        
        \item bar
        
        \item bar
        
        \item bar
        
        \item bar
        
        \item There are too many bars and not enough foo's in this list!
        
    \end{mylist}

\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So, what is your question?

Comment: @mmr I apologize for posting incomplete question. I have edited the original post. I hope the question is clear. If not, please do let me know. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert a test to check the value of `mylistii` at the beginning of the `mylist` list:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[mylist]{wide, align = left}

\newcommand{\noIorO}{%
  \let\olditem\item
  \renewcommand{\item}{%
    \ifnum\value{mylistii}=8
      \stepcounter{mylistii}% Skips (i)
    \fi
    \ifnum\value{mylistii}=14
      \stepcounter{mylistii}% Skips (o)
    \fi
    \olditem
  }%
}
\setlist[mylist, 1]{leftmargin = 0in, label = \arabic*.}
\setlist[mylist, 2]{leftmargin = 0.5in, label = (\alph*),before=\noIorO}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}
  \item Foo
  \begin{mylist}
    \item bar
    \item bar
    \item bar
    \item bar
    \item bar
    \item bar
    \item bar
    \item bar
    \item bar
    \item bar
    \item bar
    \item bar
    \item bar
    \item bar
    \item bar
    \item bar
    \item bar
    \item There are too many bars and not enough foo's in this list!
  \end{mylist}
\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can just add `\stepcounter{mylistii}`. For larger jumps you can use `\addtocounter`, e.g. `\addtocounter{mylistii}{3}`.

```
\documentclass[oneside, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\newlist{mylist}{enumerate}{2}
\setlist[mylist]{wide, align = left}

\setlist[mylist, 1]{leftmargin = 0in, label = \arabic*.}
\setlist[mylist, 2]{leftmargin = 0.5in, label = (\alph*)}

\begin{document}

\begin{mylist}
    
    \item Foo
    
    \begin{mylist}
        
        \item bar
        
        \item bar
        
        \item bar
        
        \item bar
        
        \item bar
        
        \item bar
        
        \item bar
        
        \item bar\stepcounter{mylistii}
        
        \item bar
        
        \item There are too many bars and not enough foo's in this list!
        
    \end{mylist}

\end{mylist}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your solution will require manually updating the counter. Is it possible to automate it, that is, adding a conditional statement in definition of the mylist environment?

Comment: You may need a new counter representation command and use `\AddEnumerateCounter` to make `enumitem` know it. The package doc has an example.